# Add custom js to django form

Tags: django, forms, media

I know how to do this:

```
class CalendarWidget(forms.TextInput):
    class Media:
        js = ('animations.js', 'actions.js')
```

But then i get something like: "`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://media.example.com/animations.js`">"

What I want is something like this:

```
<script>callMYFunction(sdf); </script>
```

By doing something like this:

```
class CalendarWidget(forms.TextInput):
    class Media:
        js = (callMYFunction(sdf),)
```

But I can't get this do work.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to manually add that to the `render` method of your Widget.

```
class CalendarWidget(forms.TextInput):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        out = super(CalendarWidget,self).render(name, value, attrs=attrs)
        return out + '<script type="text/javascript">callMyFunction(sdf)</script>'

    class Media:
        js = ('animations.js', 'actions.js') # callMyFunction should be defined in one of these
```